# Beginner: javascript in chrome applications

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm just starting with javascript and chrome applications (and with programming in general), and I've run up against a strange problem I can't solve. This is probably a very trivial question...

I can't seem to get scripts to work in my packaged chrome apps.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Accounting App",
  "description": "One of my first Chrome Apps.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

Background.js is:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        'bounds': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 500
        }   
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Bank Balance: </h1>
<input id="balance" placeholder="What is your current bank balance?"></input>
<h1> Owed by you: </h1>
<input id="debt" placeholder="How much do you owe?"></input>
<h1>Owed<em> to</em> you </h1>
<input id="owed" placeholder="How much is owed to you?">
<h1>How many days until you next get paid?</h1>
<input id="date" placeholder="Number of days...">
<br>
<h1><button onclick="myfunction()"> Submit </button></h1>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<p id="Result1"></p>
<p id="Result2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And myscript.js is:

```
function myfunction() {
    var balance, owed, debt, date, result1, result2;
    balance = parseInt(document.getElementById("balance").value);
    owed = parseInt(document.getElementById("owed").value);
    debt = parseInt(document.getElementById("debt").value);
    date = parseInt(document.getElementById("date").value);
    result1 = balance+debt-owed;
    result2 = result1 / date;
    document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML="You currently have " + result1 + " left to spend";
    document.getElementById("Result2").innerHTML="Daily allowance is " + result2;

}
```

The app works fine in my browser. But when I go to chrome://extensions, and "load unpackaged app", I get the page with the right styling and the right positioning, but no functionality - ie: nothing happens when I press "Submit".

I've tried a number of different examples, and have also tried putting the script into index.html, but nothing works. I always get the page with no functionality.

My guess is that I've missed some fundamental difference between a "packaged" app and a normal web page, but I can't see it. I've checked out this example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-packaged-apps-for-google-chrome
and the app works fine - but I can't see what the difference between the ToDo list example and my app is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the CSP: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html. Open the developer tools of your app to start debugging.

Comment: Hey Rob, what part of CSP do you think is being violated here?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful reply!

Comment: It turns out the CSP was the problem - the violation was my use of the event handler "onclick" inside index.html.
The solution was to add:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', myfunction);
});
to myscript.js, and remove onclick from iindex.html, giving the button the id "submit".

Answer (score 0):

To recap: my problem was the use of "onclick" in index.html, which isn't allowed with Chrome applications - as is explained in the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html):

> You can’t use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. The
>   restriction bans both  blocks and **event handlers ()**.

Instead, the handling of the "click" event needs to take place inside myscript.js.

index.html is now:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Bank Balance: </h1>
<input id="balance" placeholder="What is your current bank balance?"></input>
<h1> Owed by you: </h1>
<input id="debt" placeholder="How much do you owe?"></input>
<h1>Owed<em> to</em> you </h1>
<input id="owed" placeholder="How much is owed to you?">
<h1>How many days until you next get paid?</h1>
<input id="date" placeholder="Number of days...">
<br>
<h1><button id="submit"> Submit </button></h1>

<p id="Result1"></p>
<p id="Result2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and myscript.js is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', myfunction);
});


function myfunction() {
var balance, owed, debt, date, result1, result2;
balance = parseInt(document.getElementById("balance").value);
owed = parseInt(document.getElementById("owed").value);
debt = parseInt(document.getElementById("debt").value);
date = parseInt(document.getElementById("date").value);
result1 = balance+debt-owed;
result2 = result1 / date;
document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML="You currently have " + result1 + " left to spend";
document.getElementById("Result2").innerHTML="Daily allowance is " + result2;
};
```

The app now works fine, and no errors get picked up in the very useful debugging tools, which I had no idea existed. For beginners like me: right click the app window, and "inspect element" - it opens the developer tools, and lets you see any errors.

Thanks again for your help in this matter, Rob W!